# recent upgrade puts grub to rescue prompt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I woke up this morning to see the grub rescue prompt complaining about some highlight color being invalid. Apparently the upgrade to 14.04 was installed last night after I went to sleep.

So I am booted up on my old 12.10 disk. I tried boot-rescue, but I get the message "please close all your package managers" when attempting the recommended repair (obviously, I dont have any open).

here is my boot-info from boot-rescue: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7283446/

My system has a windows8 disk (totally separate disk), as well as a linux disk using lvm .. both ssds. And also a large data disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I had two issues I had to resolve.

One was fixing the windows 8 disk, because Boot-Rescue had corrupted it. This was done from the windows 8 install disk, dropping to the command prompt, and issuing `BootRec /FixMBR` after changing boot prioity in BIOS to get the windows 8 disk on top. Afterwards I reverted BIOS.

The other was to reinstall grub. I went to the terminal from the install DVD, then issued: `grub-install --boot-directory=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root /dev/sdb` as those were the bottable lvm and physical media I needed.

I find it curious that /dev/sdb0 exists at all, let alone that it has a very old version of the kernel sitting around there (since it isnt bootable) ... there's probably a way to reclaim a bit of disk space in the repair too .. but this was the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

This question is already asked, however, there was no good solutions for it but reinstalling the grub

[HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977) is a bug-report describing the bug briefly, and it seems like there is a bug in the Grub-package, causing upgrades to be incomplete when upgrading from older versions.

If you have a way to download and burn this, `supergrub` might help you reinstall the grub.
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Comment: Looks like a reasonable answer, if you have troble installing the Supergrubdisk thinghy you could always ask me @roberto tomás